# Using htaccess to rewrite _server[PROXY_REMOTE_ADDRESS]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not a programmer or web developer, I am a code copying bodger trying to learn so please be nice and please dont assume I have any idea what im doing :)

Is it possible to copy/rewrite the IP address returned by this variable

`_server["PROXY_REMOTE_ADDRESS"]` to `_server["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`

It has to rewrite only is there is a valid value returned by "PROXY_REMOTE_ADDRESS", if not then do not rewrite

all using the `.htaccess` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After googling the hell out of this I found out that it is not possible with out addition sever addons.

I fixed the issue in php

```html
if (isset($_SERVER['PROXY_REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = $_SERVER['PROXY_REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```